# Migrate to a test site

Tags: migration

I'm new to Craft CMS, and was wondering if it is possible to migrate a Craft CMS website to a test domain, to do redesign work, before moving the update site back to the live domain?

and will this effect any license?

looking forward to hearing from you.

Kindest regards
Anrich Vigus

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.

You may get a notice that the licence key is in use on another domain if your testing domain is publicly accessible (rather than running on your local machine). But the site will continue to work just fine.

What you can't do is run 2 "live" sites with the same key. That's a violation of the licence.

Furthermore, by going to https://id.craftcms.com/ you can manage the licences for any Craft sites you have.